# golang, How to decode json array's items in simplejson?

Tags: json, go, simplejson

incoming String is:

```
     {"status_list":[
         {"m_id":70,"m_status":"OK","m_status_code":200,"reported":false},
         {"m_id":71,"m_status":"Send Message Over Time","m_status_code":800,"reported":false},
         {"m_id":72,"m_status":"OK","m_status_code":200,"reported":false},
         {"m_id":73,"m_status":"OK","m_status_code":200,"reported":false}
         ]
      }
```

How can I get the `m_status` field of the last status element?

The way I am using is

```
import github.com/bitly/go-simplejson"

....
jsonRequest, _ := simplejson.NewJson([]byte(incommingString))
mArray := jsonRequest.Get("status_list").MustArray()
mItem := mArray[3]
fmt.printf("mItem: %")
m3StatusCode := mItem["m_status_code"]   //<---<< Can't compile
```

I got:

```
invalid operation: mItem["m_status_code"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

If I remove last line code. I can print out `mItem` as

```
mItem: : map[m_id:73 m_status:OK m_status_code:200 reported:%!s(bool=false)]
```

**QUESTION:**
How can I fetch `m_status_code` value?

Comment: The line `mArray := jsonRequest.Get("status_list").BustArray()` should be `.MustArray()`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) first.

```
m, ok := mItem.(map[string]interface{})
if(!ok){
    fmt.Println("Invalide data")
}

fmt.Println(m["m_status_code"])
```

This is because `mItem` is not actually a map. Its an `interface{}`. simplejson's [MustArray](https://godoc.org/github.com/bitly/go-simplejson#Json.MustArray) returns a `[]interface{}`.

So you have to assert that the value stored in `mItem` is of a type you can use an index `m_status_code` on.

Comment: Thank a lot!  But when I print it out, I got :   %!d(json.Number=200) how to decode it into int?

Comment: I got it! It is a string. not int yet. When I use %s in fmt.Printf(), it is fine. I got 200.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I am looking for if there is a more straightforward way. I will edit the answer if I found anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. convert to array
array, err := json.Get("status_list").Array()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
// 2. iterate
for _, item := range array {
    // 3. assertion
    if m, ok := item.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
        fmt.Println(m["m_status_code"])
    }
}
```